# Add a Word 2016 startup folder for macros in the registry

Tags: microsoft-word, windows-registry, macros

I need to set a startup-folder for my macros for Microsoft Word 2016.

I thought that adding a "**AltStartup**" registry key would work - because it works in excel but it does not seem to work with Word.

The startup-folder should be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Startup` and it should be a **trusted folder** so that my users don't receive warnings because macros are loaded.

How can I set a **registry key** so that Office will load my macros on Startup from my directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I seem to have it figured out now. 
You can add a new trusted location via registry by creating a new Registry Key like this:
`HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Security\Trusted Locations\Location99`. This is the key that has to be created.

Then it is needed to add a string `Description` with the value of the Location folder. In this case "99".

After that I have created an extensed String (REG_EXPAND_SZ) with the name `Path` and the directory I wish to add (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Startup` in my case).

So in summary:

1. Create the Location-Key
2. Add a Description String
3. Add the Path String

Following article has helped me: [Plan and configure Trusted Locations settings for Office 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179039.aspx). I wish I had found it earlier